# Touch Event Executes Five (5) Times Instead of Once

Tags: android, ios, lua, coronasdk

I'm writing a game using LUA Glider and Level Director X for making the levels along with TexturePacker to create spritesheets. I'm encountering a very unusual thing with a touch event handler.

As you can see in the code I have an object called "sign". I've assigned a touch event handler to it that calls the function "flipSign". The function flip sign checks if the touch event has ended and if so it increases a variable called "signDirection" by 1 and prints the value.

Every time I run the app and click the sign in Corona Simulator the output prints:

1
2
3
4
5

Clicking the sign again increases the variable another 5 times to 10. My understanding is the code should only increase the variable by 1 each time the sign is clicked.

Any help understanding why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```html
local composer = require( "composer" )
local scene = composer.newScene()

require("lib.LD_LoaderX")
physics = require ("physics")
physics.start()



local render = require ("render")

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Code outside of the scene event functions below will only be executed ONCE unless
-- the scene is removed entirely (not recycled) via "composer.removeScene()"
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

local myLevel = {}

local signDirection = 0


local function flipSign( event )
    
    
    if (event.phase == "ended") then
        signDirection = signDirection + 1
        print(event.phase)
        
        
    end
    return true
end

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Scene event functions
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
-- create()
function scene:create( event )
    -- Code here runs when the scene is first created but has not yet appeared on screen
    
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    myLevel= LD_Loader:new(self.view)
    myLevel:loadLevel("level_1")
    
end
 
 
-- show()
function scene:show( event )
 
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase
 
    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen)
    
        local sign = myLevel:getLayerObject("island_4", "Sign_2_4").view
        sign:addEventListener ( "touch", flipSign )
 
    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is entirely on screen
      
        
        
 
    end
end
 
 
-- hide()
function scene:hide( event )
 
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase
 
    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is on screen (but is about to go off screen)
 
    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Code here runs immediately after the scene goes entirely off screen
       
    end
end
 
 
-- destroy()
function scene:destroy( event )
 
    local sceneGroup = self.view
    -- Code here runs prior to the removal of scene's view
    myLevel:removeLevel()
    myLevel = nil

 
end
 
 
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Scene event function listeners
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
return scene
```

Answer (score 0):

In the snippet you provide, nothing is printing the value of signDirection. Rather, you have this output in `flipSign()`:

```
print(event.phase)
```

which should output:

```
ended
```

everytime a touch **ends** on the DisplayObject `sign`.  So the output you say you are getting

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

couldn't be produced by anything in the snippet.  Do you have any other touch listeners in your code?